# Vim is inserting spaces instead of tabs on some files and not others

Tags: vim

Im using the [Janus Vim distribution](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) as a starting point and I have the following in my .vimrc.after

```
set autoindent noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
set guioptions
```

This has worked well as I want a tab the equivalent of 2 spaces to be used everywhere.  Its important to note that I want a tab character and not two actual spaces.  So far this has worked great in all the files I've used, with the exeception of `.slim` files.  In this case two spaces are used.  I'm using https://github.com/slim-template/vim-slim for slim syntax highlighting.

Here is my question: how do I override whatever settings are applied to slim files and force a two-space sized tab character everywhere?

Comment: Do yourself a favor: ditch janus. Then do yourself another favor: stop trying to control the width of a tab. You cant. On any other display, it will be what it will be. All harshness aside though, I highly recommend using vim-customized-by-you (you learn the right way to do it, and its easier to debug problems), and I strongly recommend learning about filetype plugins. Also, leave tabstop at 8. If you need 2spaces for visual reasons, use 2 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to put these in `.vimrc` instead of `.vimrc.after`? I have a similar issue that I want to expand tabs normally, but not expand them for makefiles since these must be tabs to work. I have in my main `.vimrc`

```
" In general
set expandtab
" Exception for makefiles
au BufNewFile,BufRead Makefile,makefile,nmakefile set noexpandtab
```

I don't have slim syntax installed, but I'm guessing

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.slim set tabstop=2 noexpandtab
```

Comment: Filetype plugins would be better. The make one should set noexpandtab by default. Also, Janus does weird things (which is why the .after hackery)